# Sorting data in Laravel from a select with two table joins

Tags: php, sql, join, laravel

I have a database set up like this:

```
events
- id
- schedule_type (0 = single, 1 = recurring)
- title

schedule (for single events)
- id
- event_id
- date

schedule_recurring (for recurring events)
- id
- event_id
- date
```

And my query looks like this:

```
DB::table('events')
    ->left_join('schedule', 'events.id', '=', 'schedule.event_id')
    ->left_join('schedule_recurring', 'events.id', '=', 'schedule_recurring.event_id')
    ->order_by('schedule.date', 'asc')
    ->order_by('schedule_recurring.date', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

This doesn't show the date field for the schedule field, only for schedule_recurring. The date field is set to NULL in the data coming from the database. I can't figure out where my query goes wrong.

Comment: When you join a table you get all the columns from all of the joined tables - not just the matching ones.  You'll need to alias the two date columns so that they're unique.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a view as a union of `schedule` and `schedule_recurring`? Once you do that you only need to join to the view, simplifying things greatly.

Comment: Hm, never worked with views in MySQL. Any good articles or tools to do that?